# What do actual vocal ranges look like?

Tags: voice, vocal-range

I know the theoretical range for each [voice type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_type), but I would like to understand know the real ranges of singers in practice.

If you're a singer, do you have the same range as other singers with the same voice type? Can you give a few examples of actual ranges? Or maybe, does it even make sense to know you exact range?? How flexible can it be?

Comment: Not sure how to address this.  There is physics and physiology involved here perhaps beyond any musician's knowledge.  Also, a signer can extend their range.  I am fairly new to classical vocal training but I now have a three octave range from D2 to D5 and I didn't start out that way.  So, the fact that range can change kind of makes the question moot.

Comment: The range for vocalists is very varied. It's unlike an instrument, which can and usually will have a defined range. Voices are so very different, and while it's of great importance to a singer to know his/her vocal range (and a lot don't...) . Voices are not easy to pigeon-hole, individually. I understand (I think) why the question has been posed, but I don't think there's a definitive answer. If not, then there's your answer!

Comment: Voice timbre and voice range are only loosely correlated. For example  I know someone whose "sound" is very definitely a classical contralto (and her range extends down to around E3) but she can also hit and hold a C6 at any dynamic level from p to fff - which is way outside the "conventional" range for a contralto!

Comment: What I'm looking for is more like @alephzero 's comment. If you could elaborate better and give more examples... :D

Comment: There are many lists online of famous singers and their vocal range, e.g. https://www.classicfm.com/discover-music/singer-vocal-ranges/ and https://www.concerthotels.com/worlds-greatest-vocal-ranges and   https://www.newstalk.com/news/which-singer-has-the-greatest-recorded-vocal-range-of-all-time-699955

Comment: How exact a range are you looking for? I can expand my singing range by a few notes for at least the rest of the singing session with the proper warmups. But cold at the start of the day, my range is at least 3 octaves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know the theoretical range for each voice type, but I would like to understand know the real ranges of singers in practice.

Those are the estimated ranges for each of the voice ranges. From there on, each individual singer will have its own range.

> If you're a singer, do you have the same range as other singers with the same voice type?

You'll have similar ranges. Some singers of a voice type will get a little higher, some a little lower; the reference is some kind of 'mean' of the ranges. Each individual will have its own range, which will be unique to the specific singer.

> does it even make sense to know you exact range?? How flexible can it be?

As of flexibility, given a range from a singer, it can be expanded with correct training. After years of professional training, the singer gets to know the range where he/she can sing most comfortable and will, therefore, dedicate to the repertoire in that range. In that sense, it not only makes sense to know your exact range but it's what a singer naturally needs to know so he/she can keep improving and know which repertoire to perform.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Very generally speaking, yes, singers with similar voice types have similar ranges.  That information helps a singer know what types of songs fit their voice best, and whether you need to change the key of a song to something that will show your abilities best.

Comment: I think this needs to address the vide variety of ranges within each voice type.